# Creating hive table with characters in the name

Tags: hive, ddl

I am trying to create a table in hive with the following name "$example$table".
It is not allowing me to create and is giving the following error:

> *FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: [$ndo$dbproperty]: is not a valid table name*

Could anyone please help me out here? The requirement is to create tables name with characters like $,%,',' in the table name.

Comment: What version of hive are you using?  In 0.12 and earlier, only alphanumeric characters and underscores can be used in table names.

Comment: Hi ,I am on hive 1.2 .

Comment: Well, there's your answer then, you can't.

Comment: @Andrew, 1.2 > 0.12 (and it doesn't really matter anyway)

Answer (score 0):

Currently, special characters are supported only for columns, not tables.
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-6013
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-11699

**P.s. 1**
If you are brave enough you can rename the table within the metastore.

```
select * from metastore.TBLS where TBL_NAME = '$example$table';

+--------+-------------+-------+------------------+----------+-----------+-------+----------------+---------------+--------------------+--------------------+
| TBL_ID | CREATE_TIME | DB_ID | LAST_ACCESS_TIME |  OWNER   | RETENTION | SD_ID |    TBL_NAME    |   TBL_TYPE    | VIEW_EXPANDED_TEXT | VIEW_ORIGINAL_TEXT |
+--------+-------------+-------+------------------+----------+-----------+-------+----------------+---------------+--------------------+--------------------+
|    176 |  1494511100 |     2 |                0 | cloudera |         0 |   181 | $example$table | MANAGED_TABLE | (null)             | (null)             |
+--------+-------------+-------+------------------+----------+-----------+-------+----------------+---------------+--------------------+--------------------+
```

---

```
hive> select * from `$example$table`;
OK
1
2
3
Time taken: 0.58 seconds, Fetched: 3 row(s)
hive>
```

**P.s. 2**
You might want to watch "Yes (prime) minister" for a better understanding of the term **brave**