# Can we create a view name having multiple '-' or '/' in Hive

Tags: hive, hiveql

I want to create a view name which is actually a result of stored variable which looks like `school/123-324-235`. Hive doesnot allows to create such view names. But seriously if I can create such view it would be much helpful. Is there any way to name the view such with any tricks then please help.

Answer (score 0):

As per [HIVE-12381](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-12381) [HIVE-11699](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-11699) Jira's starting from **Hive-2.0** version

- we can **create hive table/view** with `/` in it's name but we are still **not able to use** **`-`** in the table names.

**Ex:**

Connected to: **Apache Hive (version 1.2.1000.2.6.4.0-91)**

```
hive> set hive.support.special.characters.tablename=true;
hive> create view `school123/245` as select * from <tb_name>;
hive> select * from `school123/245`;
hive> drop view `school123/245`;
```

Please refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43916688/creating-hive-table-with-characters-in-the-name) link for workaround for this case changing the table name in **metastore**.

Comment: sir can we use a result of a query to be the name of the view and do you know how to do it? the result may have '.' in it like `prod.school.kolkata`

Comment: @VijayaSeetharaman, if you are using `Hive` terminal then `set hive.cli.print.header=true;` this property to print out column names while selecting from the view.

Comment: you dint get my point. I want the view name to be used from a result from query. Supoose the query is `select school where the id is xyz`
The result would be `HS_School`. Can create view with that name?
I mean how to frame the create view statement like:
`create view (select school where the id is xyz)  as (Select * from <tablename> join <tablename2>)`.
I want the name coming from a select view.

Comment: @VijayaSeetharaman, **No**, it is not possible with `Hive`, while creating view we need to give `view name` and **we cannot use select query results** as `view names`.